# Ploty. ' ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.Layout: 'row''

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, conda

Deseo graficar con Ploty los resultados de cálcular el índicador Técnico MACD. Deseo dos gráficas. En la superior precios, en la inferior MACD, signal e hist. Para ello he elaborado el script siguiente.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Importamos cotizaciones
quote_closings_df = yf.download('^IBEX', start='2010-1-4', end='2019-12-30', progress=False)
df_value = quote_closings_df[['Close']]

# Cálculo del MACD
def get_macd(df_value, slow, fast, smooth):
    price = df_value['Close'].values
    exp1 = df_value.ewm(span=fast, adjust=False).mean()
    exp2 = df_value.ewm(span=slow, adjust=False).mean()
    macd = pd.DataFrame(exp1 - exp2).rename(columns={'Close': 'macd'})
    signal = pd.DataFrame(exp1.ewm(span=smooth, adjust=False).mean()).rename(columns={'Close': 'signal'})
    hist = pd.DataFrame(macd['macd'] - signal['signal']).rename(columns={0: 'hist'})
    # Crear un nuevo DataFrame para almacenar los resultados
    df_macd = pd.concat([df_value, macd, signal, hist], axis=1)
    return macd, signal, hist, df_macd


slow = 26
fast = 12
smooth = 9
macd, signal, hist, df_macd =   get_macd(df_value, slow, fast, smooth)  
       
# Gráficas MACD
import yfinance as yf
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

df_macd.reset_index(inplace=True)

# Crear los traces de la subgráfica superior
trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x = df_macd['Date'],
    y = df_macd['Close'],
    mode='lines',
    name='IBEX 35',
    line=dict(color='skyblue', width=2)
)

# Crear el layout de la subgráfica superior
layout1 = go.Layout(
    yaxis_title='Price'
)

# Crear el layout de la subgráfica inferior
layout2 = go.Layout(
    yaxis_title='IBEX 35',
    height=200
)

# Crear las subgráficas
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, vertical_spacing=0.1)
fig.add_trace(trace1, row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(trace2, row=2, col=1)
fig.add_trace(trace3, row=2, col=1)
fig.add_trace(trace4, row=2, col=1)

# Actualizar los layouts de las subgráficas
fig.update_layout(layout1, row=1, col=1)
fig.update_layout(layout2, row=2, col=1)

# Mostrar el gráfico
fig.show()


trace3 = go.Scatter(
    x = df_macd['Date'],
    y = df_macd['signal'],
    mode='lines',
    name='SIGNAL',
    line=dict(color='skyblue', width=1.5)
)

trace4 = go.Bar(
    x =df_macd['Date'],
    y = df_macd['hist'],
    marker=dict(
        color=df_macd['hist'],
        colorscale=[[0, '#ef5350'], [1, '#26a69a']],
        reversescale=True
    ),
    opacity=0.5,
    name='HISTOGRAM'
)

# Crear el layout de la subgráfica inferior
layout2 = go.Layout(
    yaxis = dict(title='IBEX 35'),
    xaxis = dict(title='Date'),
    height = 200
)

# Crear las subgráficas
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, vertical_spacing=0.1)
fig.add_trace(trace1, row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(trace2, row=2, col=1)
fig.add_trace(trace3, row=2, col=1)
fig.add_trace(trace4, row=2, col=1)

# Actualizar los layouts de las subgráficas
fig.update_layout(layout1, row=1, col=1)
fig.update_layout(layout2, row=2, col=1)

# Mostrar el gráfico
fig.show()
```

Al ejecutarlo, me devuelve.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[20], line 62
     59 fig.add_trace(trace4, row=2, col=1)
     61 # Actualizar los layouts de las subgráficas
---> 62 fig.update_layout(layout1, row=1, col=1)
     63 fig.update_layout(layout2, row=2, col=1)
     65 # Mostrar el gráfico

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.8/site-packages/plotly/graph_objs/_figure.py:775, in Figure.update_layout(self, dict1, overwrite, **kwargs)
    749 def update_layout(self, dict1=None, overwrite=False, **kwargs) -> "Figure":
    750     """
    751 
    752     Update the properties of the figure's layout with a dict and/or with
   (...)
    773 
    774     """
--> 775     return super(Figure, self).update_layout(dict1, overwrite, **kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.8/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py:1393, in BaseFigure.update_layout(self, dict1, overwrite, **kwargs)
   1369 def update_layout(self, dict1=None, overwrite=False, **kwargs):
   1370     """
   1371     Update the properties of the figure's layout with a dict and/or with
   1372     keyword arguments.
   (...)
   1391         The Figure object that the update_layout method was called on
   1392     """
-> 1393     self.layout.update(dict1, overwrite=overwrite, **kwargs)
   1394     return self

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.8/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py:5114, in BasePlotlyType.update(self, dict1, overwrite, **kwargs)
   5112     with self.figure.batch_update():
   5113         BaseFigure._perform_update(self, dict1, overwrite=overwrite)
-> 5114         BaseFigure._perform_update(self, kwargs, overwrite=overwrite)
   5115 else:
   5116     BaseFigure._perform_update(self, dict1, overwrite=overwrite)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.8/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py:3877, in BaseFigure._perform_update(plotly_obj, update_obj, overwrite)
   3873                 continue
   3874         # If no match, raise the error, which should already
   3875         # contain the _raise_on_invalid_property_error
   3876         # generated message
-> 3877         raise err
   3879 # Convert update_obj to dict
   3880 # --------------------------
   3881 if isinstance(update_obj, BasePlotlyType):

ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.Layout: 'row'

Did you mean "font"?

    Valid properties:
        activeselection
            :class:`plotly.graph_objects.layout.Activeselection`
            instance or dict with compatible properties
...........................................................
        yaxis
            :class:`plotly.graph_objects.layout.YAxis` instance or
            dict with compatible properties
        
Did you mean "font"?

Bad property path:
row
^^^
```

¿Cuál es la causa y cómo puedo solucionarlo?- Tengo instalado ploty 5.13.0